# How to specify sequence on non-id column in Grails?

Tags: grails

I am trying to map a column in grails to a sequence, but this column is not the id.

```
Integer seqCol
```

I have tried the following code in static mapping, I'm basically just switching 'id' with 'colum'.

```
column name: "seqCol", generator: "sequence", params:[sequence:"SEQUENCE_NAME"]
```

This returns an error on save, saying that seqCol cannot be null which leads me to believe the mapping failed.

Comment: As workaround you can use beforeInsert event to set value for seqCol.


 def beforeInsert() {
         seqCol = //select nexVal from "SEQUENCE_NAME"

   }

Comment: Were you able to try my suggested answer? Let me know if there is any change.

Answer (score -1):

In order to change the name of the id property, you need to specify the name for the id property.

```
Integer seqCol

static mapping = {
   id name: 'seqCol', column: 'seq_col', generator: "sequence", params:[sequence:"SEQUENCE_NAME"]  
}
```

Comment: I think this isn't what he is looking, you are making the seqCol the "id" of the domain object, and he wants to assign a non id field with a sequence